# RS232 switching matrix for multiple devices and PCs?

Tags: serial-port, switching, multiplexing

I have six pieces of equipment which con be controlled via RS232. I want to be able to select which pieces of equipment are connected to any one of my three computers at a given time.

I know that I can't have a device connected to more than one PC at a time;  but, I want to be able to select which PC each device is currently being connected to.

Each PC already has two RS232 ports and will only ever be connected to (at most) two pieces of equipment.

I'm trying to determine what equipment I can buy to achieve this, understanding that I may need to cascade multiple switches/etc.

So for example, Gear A and B might be going to PC1. Gear D is going to PC2. Gear C and F are going to PC3. And then tomorrow I want to change things around and switch which PC each piece of equipment is connected to.

Has anyone ever done something like this?

Comment: ...it is so difficult to unplug them? I mean you didn't say how many PC you want eventually to connect (M). So you need a multi switch with 6 input and 2xM output. I see it difficult. Are you searching solution as little LAN of arduino devices with network adapter and RS232 and then a software to switch them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use any kind of [terminal server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_server), you will be able to connect any device to any PC (hardware RS-232 ports aren't required).

> A terminal server (also referred to as a serial server or console server network access server) enables organizations to connect devices with an RS-232, RS-422 or RS-485 serial interface to a local area network (LAN).

So you connecting all you gears to terminal server and have them accessible trough LAN to any computer in your network as:

- Virtual serial ports on selected PC (driver installation required).
- Listening IP ports on terminal server IP address.
- Other less often used modes.

I can recommend you a Moxa [Serial Device Servers](http://www.moxa.com/product/SDS_SerialDevice%20Servers.htm) (some setups - virtual serial ports - might require Windows). You can find there:

- 19 inch rack-mounted: [NPort 5610/NPort 5630 Series](http://www.moxa.com/product/NPort_5600.htm).
- Desktop with LCD panel: [NPort 5610-8-DT/NPort 5650-8-DT Series](http://www.moxa.com/product/NPort_5600-8-DT.htm).
- Basic desktop: [NPort 5610-8-DTL/NPort 5650-8-DTL Series](http://www.moxa.com/product/NPort_5600-8-DTL.htm).

Comment: @MichaelMankus You are welcome.